# Is it possible for two variables to point to the same piece of memory?

Tags: java, object-oriented

Is it possible for two variables to point to the same piece of memory?

My professor wrote a short snippet of code where he created a second instantiation of a class and assigned it a previously created object and referred to this as two variables pointing to the same location/info in the memory, which left me pretty confused

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such thing as an object name in Java. Classes have names like `java.util.ArrayList`. But instances of `ArrayList` are objects that have no name. You make them when you run code like `new ArrayList()`. They will live in different memory locations that you remember with references. Those you give names.

```
ArrayList al1 = new ArrayList(); // Object 1 being constructed at some address
ArrayList al2 = new ArrayList(); // Object 2 being constructed somewhere else
ArrayList al3 = al2;             // No object is being constructed here
```

Here are 3 references.  `al1` refers to object 1. `al2` and `al3` refer to object 2.  So you can have two references to the same object. But that object still only lives in one place, at one address.  And again those aren't the name of the object. Those are the names of the references that point to that object.

My favorite metaphor for this is: you can hand out as many business cards with your home address on them as you like but you still only have one house.  You can name each business card (reference). You can name the house blueprints (the class) but you can't name the actual house (object).

The only truly 1 to 1 identifier an object has is it's address which you never see in Java unless you write some crazy code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16351592/1493294).

Us mere mortals make do with using references, hashcodes, and Id fields to keep track of which object we have.  That only sounds complicated because it is.

Answer (score 18):

> Can a single object in Java have two distinct names?

In Java, objects don't have names, they have references.

Variables of all sorts have names, but variables are distinct from objects.  Variables can reference objects.

> Is it possible for two <strike>object names</strike> *references* to point to the same *object* (i.e. piece of memory) ?

Yes, two or more references, say from parameters and/or local variables and/or instance variables and/or static variables can all reference the same object.

This is what happens when you copy a variable that is an object type (by simple assignment, e.g. `a = b;`): the reference is copied, i.e. duplicated — while the object itself is unaffected by such an assignment (it is only affected by what you might do later with the reference).  By such an assignment the new variable, post assignment, refers to the same object, and the old variable's reference continues to remain valid.

This same kind of reference copy happens during parameter passing, which is just like assignment.

Of course, any (active) reference keeps the object from being garbage collected.

A valid reference is one that is still in scope or reachable by something that is still in scope.  When a function ends, all its local variables and parameters go out of scope, releasing any references those hold.

Comment: FYI, I looked for a duplicate for this question but did not find an obvious one!

Comment: Only primitives are copied when assigned, though if you prefer for a primitive to have its reference copied, you'd need to "box" it, which is to say, use its class equivalent (Integer for int, Double for double, etc.).

Comment: “scope” is a compile-time concept that is irrelevant to the garbage collector. It is possible that a reference variable is still in scope, but the referenced object considered unreachable, because no subsequent code touches it.